# I cannot fix this undefined field issue when trying to update firebase document in vuejs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update my firebase document by keep getting this error'

> FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field id in document courses/1wY9RjpYtNeEDtuaeXmh)

This is my GameForm vue component code:

```
<template>
    <div class="game-form">
        <v-btn @click="dialog = !dialog" color="primary" v-if="!course">Add new game</v-btn>
        <v-btn @click="dialog = !dialog; setData()" color="primary" v-else>Edit game</v-btn>

        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent width="600px">
            <v-card>
                <v-card-title v-if="!course">Add new game</v-card-title>
                <v-card-title v-else>Edit game</v-card-title>
                <v-card-text>
                    <v-form
                        v-model="valid"
                        lazy-validation
                        ref="form"
                    >
                        <v-text-field
                            v-model="subject"
                            :rules="fieldRules"
                            label="Subject"
                            required
                            outline
                        >
                        </v-text-field>
                        
                        <v-textarea
                            v-model="description"
                            :rules="fieldRules"
                            label="Game developer"
                            outlined
                            required
                        >
                        </v-textarea>

                        <v-text-field
                            v-model="duration"
                            :rules="fieldRules"
                            label="Duration"
                            outlined
                            required
                        >
                        </v-text-field>

                        <v-textarea
                            v-model="payment"
                            :rules="fieldRules"
                            label="Payment"
                            outlined
                            required
                        >
                        </v-textarea>

                        <v-textarea
                            v-model="years_exp"
                            :rules="fieldRules"
                            label="Experience"
                            outlined
                            required
                        >
                        </v-textarea>

                        <v-textarea
                            v-model="tutor"
                            :rules="fieldRules"
                            label="Tutor"
                            outlined
                            required
                        >
                        </v-textarea>

                          <v-textarea
                            v-model="amount"
                            :rules="fieldRules"
                            label="Amount"
                            outlined
                            required
                        >
                        </v-textarea>

                        <!-- <v-textarea
                            v-model="years_exp"
                            :rules="fieldRules"
                            label="Game description"
                            outlined
                            required
                        >
                        </v-textarea> -->

                        <v-file-input
                            accept="image/*"
                            label="File input"
                            v-model="file"
                            show-size
                        >
                        </v-file-input>
                        <p>Current image: <a v-if="oldImage" :href="oldImage">link</a></p>

                        <v-btn
                            elevation="2"
                            color="primary"
                            @click="storeGame"
                            :loading="isLoading"
                            v-if="!course"
                        >
                            Store
                        </v-btn>
                        <v-btn
                            elevation="2"
                            color="primary"
                            @click="updateGame"
                            :loading="isLoading"
                            v-else
                        >
                            Update
                        </v-btn>
                    </v-form>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn
                        color="blue darken-1"
                        text
                        @click="dialog = false"
                    >
                        Close
                    </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { coursesCollection, auth, storage } from '../firebase'
export default {
    name: 'GameForm',
    props: ['course', 'index'],
    data() {
        return {
            isLoading: false,
            valid: false,
            dialog: false,
            subject: '',
            description: '',
            tutor: '',
            payment: 0,
            duration: '',
            amount: 0,
            years_exp: 0,
            file: null,
            fieldRules: [
                v => !!v || 'this field is required'
            ],
            oldImage: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        resetForm() {
            this.$refs.form.reset()
        },
        async storeGame() {
            try {
                this.isLoading = false
                // upload file
                const fileRef = 'uploads/courses/' + this.file.name
                const snapshot = await storage.ref(fileRef).put(this.file)
                let data = {
                    userId: auth.currentUser.uid,
                    subject: this.subject,
                    description: this.description,
                    tutor: this.tutor,
                    payment: this.payment,
                    duration: this.duration,
                    amount: this.amount,
                    years_exp: this.years_exp,
                    image: fileRef
                }
                const doc = await coursesCollection.add(data)
                this.$emit('course:added', data)
                await this.resetForm()
                this.isLoading = false
                this.dialog = false
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        },
        async updateGame() {
            try {
                this.isLoading = false
                let data = {
                    id: this.id,
                    userId: auth.currentUser.uid,
                    subject: this.subject,
                    description: this.description,
                    tutor: this.tutor,
                    payment: this.payment,
                    duration: this.duration,
                    amount: this.amount,
                    years_exp: this.years_exp,
                }
                
                if(this.file) {
                    // delete oldImage
                    const fileRefOld = this.course.img
                    await storage.ref(fileRefOld).delete()
                    // upload file
                    const fileRef = 'uploads/courses/' + this.file.name
                    const snapshot = await storage.ref(fileRef).put(this.file)
                    data.image = fileRef
                } else {
                    data.image = this.course.image
                }
                const doc = await coursesCollection.doc(this.course.id).update(data)
                // await this.resetForm()
                this.isLoading = false
                this.dialog = false
                data.index = this.index
                // this.$emit('course:updated', data)
                alert('Game updated!')
            } catch(e) {
                // console.log(this.course.id);
                console.log(e)
            }
        },
        setData() {
            if(this.course) {
                this.subject =  this.course.subject,
                this.description =  this.course.description,
                this.tutor =  this.course.tutor,
                this.payment =  this.course.payment,
                this.duration =  this.course.duration,
                this.amount =  this.course.amount,
                this.years_exp =  this.course.years_exp,
                this.oldImage = this.course.image
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.setData()
    }
}
</script>
```

This is my Dashboard Page

```
<template>
    <div class="dashboard">
        <h1>Hi, {{ userProfile.name }}</h1>
        <GameForm @course:added="addGame" />
        <v-row>
            <v-col md="4" v-for="(course, index) in courses" :key="course.id">
                <v-card>
                    <v-img
                        v-if="course.image"
                        height="250"
                        :src="course.image"
                        lazy-src="https://via.placeholder.com/250"
                    >
                    </v-img>
                    <v-card-title>{{ course.subject }}</v-card-title>
                    <v-card-text>
                        <p class="subtitle-1">tutor: {{ course.tutor }}</p>
                        <p class="subtitle-1">duration: {{ course.duration }}</p>
                        <p>{{ course.description }}</p>
                    </v-card-text>
                    <v-card-actions>
                        <GameForm :course="course" :index="index" @course:updated="updateGame" />
                        <v-btn color="red" @click="deleteConfirm(course.id, course.subject)" text>Delete</v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>

        <v-dialog
            v-model="deleteDialog"
            max-width="400"
        >
            <v-card>
                <v-card-title class="headline">
                    Delete Game?
                </v-card-title>
                <v-card-text>Are you sure you want to delete <b>{{ pTitle }}</b>?</v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-btn text color="red" @click="deleteGame">Delete</v-btn>
                    <v-btn @click="deleteDialog = false" text color="secondary">Close</v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
<br><br><br><br><br>
        <v-row>
        <v-layout>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6>
        <v-card hover>
          
          <v-responsive
            height="auto"
          >
          <!-- <v-img 
            src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ijklim/simon-game/gh-pages/assets/img/bg--game-pad.jpg"
          >

          </v-img> -->
          <Play />
          </v-responsive>

          <v-card-title>
            <h2>v-card-title</h2>
          </v-card-title>
          
          <v-card-text>
            line 1<br>
            line 2<br>
            line 3
          </v-card-text>
          
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn color=success>Click #1</v-btn>
            <v-btn text color=primary>Click #2</v-btn>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn icon><v-icon>b</v-icon></v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
          
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    </v-row>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import GameForm from '@/components/GameForm'
import Play from './Play'
import { auth, storage, coursesCollection } from '../firebase'
export default {
    components: {
        GameForm,
        Play
    },
    data() {
        return {
            courses: [],
            pId: null,
            pTitle: null,
            deleteDialog: false,
            userProfile: {}
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState(['userProfile'])
    },
    methods: {
        async addGame(doc) {
            let img = ''
            if(doc.image) {
                img = await storage.ref().child(doc.image).getDownloadURL()
            }
            this.courses.push({
                id: doc.id,
                subject: doc.subject,
                description: doc.description,
                tutor: doc.tutor,
                payment: doc.payment,
                duration: doc.duration,
                amount: doc.amount,
                years_exp: doc.years_exp,                
                image: img,
                img: doc.image
            })
        },
        async updateGame(doc) {
            let img = ''
            if(doc.image) {
                img = await storage.ref().child(doc.image).getDownloadURL()
            }
            if (doc.id) {
                console.log('u', doc.tutor),
                this.courses.splice(doc.index, 0, {
                id: doc.id,
                subject: doc.subject,
                description: doc.description,
                tutor: doc.tutor,
                payment: doc.payment,
                duration: doc.duration,
                amount: doc.amount,
                years_exp: doc.years_exp,                
                image: img,
                img: doc.image
            })
            }
        },
        async getGames() {
            try {
                const querySnapshot = await coursesCollection.where('userId', '==', auth.currentUser.uid).get()
                querySnapshot.forEach( async (doc) => {
                    let img = ''
                    if(doc.data().image) {
                        img = await storage.ref().child(doc.data().image).getDownloadURL()
                    }
                    this.courses.push({
                        id: doc.data().id,
                        subject: doc.data().subject,
                        description: doc.data().description,
                        tutor: doc.data().tutor,
                        payment: doc.data().payment,
                        duration: doc.data().duration,
                        amount: doc.data().amount,
                        years_exp: doc.data().years_exp,
                        image: img,
                        img: doc.data().image
                    })
                })
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        },
        async deleteConfirm(id, subject) {
            this.deleteDialog = true
            this.pId = id
            console.log(this.pId)
            this.pTitle = subject
        },
        async deleteGame() {
            try {
                await coursesCollection.doc(this.pId).delete()
                alert('Course deleted!')
                // remove game from array
                this.courses.splice(this.courses.findIndex(x => x.id == this.pId), 1)
                this.deleteDialog = false
                // reset
                this.pId = null
                this.pTitle = null
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        }
    },
    async mounted() {
        await this.getGames()
    }
}
</script>
```

This is my store.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import * as fb from '../firebase'
import router from '../router/index'


Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    userProfile: {},
    isAuthenticated: false
  },
  mutations: {
    setUserProfile(state, val, authState) {
      state.isAuthenticated = !state.isAuthenticated
      state.userProfile = val
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async register({ dispatch}, form) {
      // sign up user
      const { user } = await fb.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(form.email, form.password)

      // create user profile object
      await fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).set({
        name: form.name
      })

      // fetch user profile
      dispatch('fetchUserProfile', user)
    },
    async login({ dispatch }, form) {
      // sign in user
      const { user } = await fb.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(form.email, form.password)

      // fetch user profile
      dispatch('fetchUserProfile', user)
    },
    async fetchUserProfile({ commit }, user) {
      // fetch user profile
      const userProfile = await fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).get()

      // set user profile
      commit('setUserProfile', userProfile.data())

      // change route or redirect
      router.push('/dashboard')
    },
    async logout({ commit }) {
      await fb.auth.signOut()
      commit('setUserProfile', {})
      router.push('/')
    }
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

When i check in dev tools, userProfile, pId, PTitle are all undefined.

I am new to vue and firebase, so I am stuck. Could you direct me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because one of the properties in the `data` object you pass to `await coursesCollection.doc(this.course.id).update(data)` is undefined.

You should debug your code and find which property(ies) of this object is(are) undefined:

```
            let data = {
                id: this.id,
                userId: auth.currentUser.uid,
                subject: this.subject,
                description: this.description,
                tutor: this.tutor,
                payment: this.payment,
                duration: this.duration,
                amount: this.amount,
                years_exp: this.years_exp,
            }
```

Comment: Thank @Renaud. I checked over and over and i think i defined all of them in the data object. I just cannot figure it out by myself. I have edited my question to include more codes to explain my question further. Thanks again.

Comment: @AbarugoGoodness Renaud pretty much has it, `id: this.id` is your undefined value - "found in field **id** in document". It should be `id: this.course.id` because in your `setData()` method you don't copy it across from `this.course` like you do with the other properties.

Comment: Oh, I check again and 'id' is undefined. How do i get it? Is there a different way to get it, since i have other fields retrieved successfully.
Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks so much, @samthecodingman, I changed it to >this.course.id, yet it is undefined

Comment: @AbarugoGoodness It doesn't look like you ever attached the ID in the document's data. Instead of `const doc = await coursesCollection.add(data)`, you'll need to use `const docRef = coursesCollection.doc(); data.id = docRef.id; const doc = await docRef.set(data);`.

Comment: @samthecodingman, You've saved me. I am grateful.
When i update now, I get "asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:6 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'https:/firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lombaz-swift-test.appspot.com/o/uploads%2Fcourses%2F1.JPG?alt=media&token=a49d537e-4f9b-44a9-91ad-5506a3041739' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)"  in image field instead of 'uploads/courses/filename'. Could this be associated with the correction i made?. Thanks again